# Pip3: Ansible install to 3.0.0 not working, still shows old packages

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am trying to install Ansible-3.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04, but it's not working out. It's still showing me the old version i.e 2.10.9.

I have already executed install command, which shows it's working but still pointing to old version. What am I doing wrong?

Terminal:

```
 ansible --version
ansible 2.10.9
  configured module search path = ['/home/akshay/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Then I installed Ansible as regular user.

```
pip3 install --upgrade ansible==3.0.0
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ansible==3.0.0 in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5 in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible==3.0.0) (2.10.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (3.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography->ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jinja2->ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (2.0.1)
```

But still the same

```
akshay@akshay-System-Product-Name ~/D/R/p/n/c/e/staging-database (master)> ansible --version
ansible 2.10.9
  configured module search path = ['/home/akshay/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Even tried with sudo

```
akshay@akshay-System-Product-Name ~/D/R/p/n/c/e/staging-database (master)> sudo pip3 install ansible==3.0.0
[sudo] password for akshay:           
Requirement already satisfied: ansible==3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from ansible==3.0.0) (2.10.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jinja2->ansible-base<2.11,>=2.10.5->ansible==3.0.0) (2.0.1)
```

what am I missing?

I am trying to fix this issue

```
Restriction: only Ansible =2.11.X is supported.
```

Comment: It looks like the `/usr/bin/ansible` file is not being affected by any of your attempts to upgrade with pip. Your non-root attempt installs ansible 3.0.0 into a virtualenv in your home directory, but the `/usr/bin/ansible` is likely prioritized in your shell's PATH. Similarly, the `sudo` pip install appears to be installing pip 3.0.0 to the site-packages directory, but that may still not be affecting the `/usr/bin/ansible` file. If you installed ansible with another method such as an OS package, that is the most likely explanation. upgrade or remove via the initial install method.

Comment: @programmerq: I can purge the files, but I don't remember how I installed it. I am still not able to find the binaries for ansible-3.0.0. I can only find libs, if there were binaries, I could just update the path. :-)

Comment: This seems to have devolved into a "I have no idea what versions of anything are installed on my machine," which is not a programming question (what `if` would one change to fix that problem?). You are welcome to blow away `/usr/local/lib/python3.8` and `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.8` to put yourself back in a good state, but trying to troubleshoot `sudo` commands over stackoverflow comments is the road to ruin

Answer (score 2):

You have gotten bitten by the confusing ansible rebrand; ansible from pip's perspective is no longer just one thing, it's [a distribution of selected versions](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-build-data/blob/3.0.0/3/ansible-3.0.0.deps) of [ansible-collections](https://github.com/ansible-collections) plus [a selected version of "ansible-core"](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-build-data/blob/main/3/ansible-3.0.0.deps#L2) (previously known as ansible), with the latter selected version that you're seeing emitted by `--version`.

You will never(?) see 3.0.0 (nor 4.2.0, [the current version](https://pypi.org/project/ansible/#history)) output by `ansible --version` because the ansible *command* is, in fact, still 2.10.5, but the ansible PyPI package is the 3.0.0 that is being installed

You can confirm this theory for yourself by installing ansible into a docker container, or virtual machine, or whatever clean environment, and then run `ansible --version` and observe it does not say the same version as you requested installed by pip

It's a huge, monster, terrible mess

Comment: You might be right, I get this error

Restriction: only Ansible =2.11.X is supported.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Same error for me. How to fix this mess ... ?  Any idea ?